# DB2 Installation in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How can i connect with db2 AS400 in ruby without using jruby. 
I am trying to install ibm_db gem in console , but it's throwing error like below

```
    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ibm_db-.0.0/ext
    C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190531-15036-er6nbm.rb extconf.rb Detected 64-bit Ruby

    Environment variable IBM_DB_HOME is not set. Set it to your 
    DB2/IBM_Data_Server_Driver installation directory and retry gem install.
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ibm_db/4.0.0) for the gem seems to say that only 32bit ruby is supported on Windows.

> README for the IBM_DB Adapter (4.0.0) and Driver (3.0.5) (2018/05/24)
>   For ActiveRecord Version >= 5.0.7 (and Rails >= 5.0.7)
>
> Supported Operating Systems
>
> - Linux 32/64 bit
> - Microsoft Windows 32 bit
> - IBM AIX 32/64 bit
> - HP-UX 32/64 bit
> - Sun Solaris 32/64 bit